# Change settings for App that has status "Waiting for Upload"

Tags: app-store-connect

I accidentally asked iTunes Connect to automatically release the app upon approval.
Now I can't figure out how to change this, I can upload and reject a binary, but not select "start over" with supplying details for a version.

Does anyone know this problem and the solution?

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972109/itunes-connect-how-revert-app-status-from-waiting-for-upload-to-prepare-for-upl):

1. Upload the current binary.
2. Make it "developer rejected".
3. Change to Ready for Upload with your new settings