# iTunes Connect: How revert app status from waiting for upload to Prepare for upload

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm uploading the first version of my iOS application for review, Whereas my application has an In-App purchase. I made my app status to Ready for upload while getting in its Binary upload section. But later I got that I have to submit my first In-App purchase along application version.

Now I can't edit In-App purchase section in application version meta data as it states that you can't submit in app purchase with this version as its already submitted for review.

I haven't uploaded binary yet in this version, now two solutions which I think could be

1- I email Apple review team to change my app status from Ready to upload back to Prepare for upload
 OR
2- Upload a binary and then reject it but I'm confused that whether rejecting binary would revert my app status to Prepare for upload or Waiting for upload.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to submit any IAPs with my first binary and got rejected ("can't purchase anything = can't review app"). I also hurried and clicked 'ready to upload binary' without editing IAPs first. I just submitted the same binary again and quickly rejected it. Then, I could edit IAPs, and finally re-submitted the binary one more time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1.Upload the current binary.

2.Make it "developer rejected".

3.Upload a new binary of your choice.